# Contact Form that shows new page then reverts back to home page?

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I have a basic contact form on my site that works fine. When submitted though it opens a blank page with "Thank you" ... I would like to potentially open a styled web page that says "submitted successfully" displays for around 3 seconds, then reverts back to the main page. I'm quite new to web design and especially PHP so if anyone could give any tips that would be great. I have put the PHP code below:

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent = "From: $name \r\n Message: $message";
$recipient = "myemail@email.com";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $message, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

Comment: You arent even submitting the form?

Comment: I've tested it twice and both emails are coming through to the inbox.

Comment: Okay wait I got it. I'll answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<?php 

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent = "From: $name \r\n Message: $message";
$recipient = "myemail@email.com";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $message, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url=http://mysite.com/contact.php">
    </head>
    <body>
       <p>Submitted successfully</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

If the email is sent, the message "Submitted successfully" will show. Three seconds later, it will redirect to `http://mysite.com/contact.php`. Change `http://mysite.com/contact.php` to the URL you want to return to.

Comment: I was about to answer this but shouldn't he add submitting it? As I do think he uses a button

Comment: @Loko I think that he's submitting it from another page.

Comment: @Loko Sorry. Had to edit my comment. I hit enter by mistake :/

Comment: Can I ask why? The information gets sent to my email perfectly fine. Please tell me if I'm missing something.

Comment: @user2970070 You could just do everything in one page

Answer (score 0):

Although Wayne Whitty's answer is right, I do have another note/answer:

To redirect after 3 seconds use this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=http://YOURPAGE.php">
```

I see you are redirecting from a different page but that is pretty useless. You could also just put this in the main page and use this to only redirect after submitting. (The form is an example, I dont know how your form looks like)

```
<form action="register.php" method="post">
Username <input type="text" name="name">
Password <input type="text" name="email">
Message <input type="text" name="message">
<input name="register" type="submit" value="Register">
</form>


<?php 
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
echo'<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=http://YOURPAGE.php">';
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent = "From: $name \r\n Message: $message";
$recipient = "myemail@email.com";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $message, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "submitted successfully";
}
?>
```

Also just replace: `echo "Thank You!";` with `echo "submitted successfully";`

Comment: @user2970070 Did it work for you? If yes dont forget to accept an answer. Also if Wayne Whittys answer was more helpfull, then by all needs accept his answer.